# How to add my name on every page corner in Lyx?

Tags: header-footer, lyx

My teacher has asked me to add my name on every page of my report. Is there a nice way of doing this so my name appears in a subtle way?

Comment: Where do you want your name? (e.g. upper left corner)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You can use [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.mirror.rafal.ca/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf) package to format headers and footers.

Comment: Add it to a header or footer. What document class are you using?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For adding your name to the header/footer, LyX provides "fancy" heading via the [`fancyhdr` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr). First, activate these style headings (Document > Settings... > Page Layout > Heading Style):

[image]

Now add the following code to your LaTeX Preamble (also under Document > Settings...):

```
\fancyhf{}               % Clear fancy header/footer
\fancyfoot[L]{My name}   % My name in Left footer
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}  % Page number in Right footer
\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@fancy   % Plain page style = fancy page style
\makeatother
```

The first three lines set clears the header/footer, and sets the `L` and `R` footer respectively. The last three lines replaces the `plain` page style (typically associated with title pages and the like) to be equivalent to the `fancy` page style. This might not be necessary in your case.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a solution that doesn't require headers or footers. It exploits the command `\AddToShipoutPicture` of the [`eso-pic`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) package.

I'm assuming that you want your name in the upper left corner, but it can be adjusted to be everywhere in the page.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{blindtext} % just for the example

\AddToShipoutPicture{%
  \AtPageUpperLeft{%
    \hspace*{20pt}\makebox(200,-20)[lt]{%
      \footnotesize%
      \textbf{user42356}%
}}}

\begin{document}

\blinddocument % just for the example

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

P.S. To add this stuff in the preamble in LyX, go to Document --> Settings --> LaTeX Preamble and insert the required lines, i.e.

```
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\AddToShipoutPicture{%
  \AtPageUpperLeft{%
    \hspace*{20pt}\makebox(200,-20)[lt]{%
      \footnotesize%
      \textbf{user42356}%
}}}
```

Comment: As the OP uses LyX, one could mention for completeness that the preamble part should be added to Document --> Settings --> LaTeX Preamble.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks for the advice. I'll add in the answer. I don't know Lyx at all (never used it).